# Logs not generated in docker compose

Tags: python, logging, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose for dev environment.
My docker compose file is,

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3310:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: some pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: some db
      MYSQL_USER: some user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: some pass
  onehop:
    build:
      context: . #current dir as build context
      args:
        mysql_host: 127.0.0.1
        mysql_port: 3306
        mysql_user: onehop
        mysql_passwd: onehop
        mysql_db: onehop
        celery_host: some host
        celery_port: some port
        celery_user: some user
        celery_password: some password
        app_env: SomeDev
    volumes:
      - ../../.:/code
    working_dir: /code/
    environment:
      ONEHOP_ENV: PranavDev6530
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 0
    command: bash -c "pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py runserver updatedb"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
```

I use a function that looks for logging config, and if it's already configured, provides the logging instance, it's as follows,

```
def get_logger(logger_name=None):
    global __logging_configured
    if not __logging_configured:
        logging.config.dictConfig(CONFIG.LOGGING_CONFIG)
        __logging_configured = True
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name or CONFIG.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME)
    return logger
```

I call `get_logger('logger name')` to get the logger.

`CONFIG.LOGGING_CONFIG` is a dict as follows,

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = dict(
        version=1,
        formatters={
            'compact': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8.8s] %(name)-10.10s : %(message)s'
            },
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8.8s] %(name)-8.8s [%(filename)-15.15s:%(lineno)-3.3s]: %(message)s'
            },
            'err_report': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s\n%(message)s'
            }
        },
        handlers={
            'slack_jabber': {
                'class': 'contrib.slacker.SlackHandler',
                'url': 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/lol',
                'channel': 'somedev',
                'username': 'crash_jabber',
                'icon_emoji': ':ghost:'
            },
            'cron': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'filename': '%s/%s' % (pwd, '../logs/cron/cron.log'),
                'interval': 1,
                'when': 'midnight',
                'encoding': 'utf8'
            },
            'api': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'filename': '%s/%s' % (pwd, '../logs/api/api.log'),
                'interval': 1,
                'when': 'midnight',
                'encoding': 'utf8'
            },
            'critical_err': {
                'class': 'logging.handlers.SMTPHandler',
                'formatter': 'err_report',
                'mailhost': ("localhost", 25),
                'fromaddr': 'no-reply@company.co',
                'toaddrs': [
                    'lol@lol.com'
                ],
                'subject': '[Dev] Onehop : Something bad happened'
            },
            'default': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
        },
        loggers={
            '': {
                'handlers': ['default'],
                'level': 'DEBUG'
            },
            'cron': {
                'handlers': ['cron'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False
            },
            'api': {
                'handlers': ['api', 'default'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False
            },
            'crash': {
                'handlers': ['critical_err', 'api', 'slack_jabber'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': False
            }
        }
    )
```

The current setup, perfectly works on my ubuntu machine, but somehow logs are not getting generated inside docker container, once I do `docker-compose up` with `sudo`.
I'm pretty new to docker-compose, am I missing some setting for `docker-compose.yaml`? Thanks.

Comment: what is the normal behaviour when the program isn't running in the container? Log files get logged to somewhere? Have you hop inside the docker container to see if your files are in the container?

Comment: Outside docker, it works fine. e.g. let's say I want to use 'api' logger, in that case, logs are generated in file as well as it'll be printed on terminal. But, inside docker no logs are generated, neither in file nor on terminal.

Comment: From what I know is that `docker` logs stdout of your program within a container. It is strange to see nothing gets printed out thou. As mentioned earlier have you tried attaching your container and do a `find . -name cron.log`? `docker -i -t [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash`. Otherwise if nothing is there I will try checking the `get_logger` routine and make sure something is returned.

Comment: @SamuelToh, I logged into container and printed file, but it's empty. :(

Comment: When you say you 'printed the file but it is empty' do you mean the file is there but it has no content within it? If that is the case then can you confirm that the application is doing what it is suppose to be and it isn't getting stuck for other reason hence not writing any log? Otherwise, if the file isn't there can you try doing a `touch test.txt` command at the directory where the log is supposed to be written, **in** the container to eliminate possibility of a permission issue?

Comment: The empty file is copied from host to docker container, when I do `sudo docker-compose up`.

Comment: If we are talking about logs created by mysql, then I would like to tell that mysql can write logs only if it has ownership of files. This issue has been raised at [docker-library/mysql](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/146)